# UIScrollView wrong offset

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have several labels inside an scrollview. Each label is an "page". But the offset isn't right. And I can't find the problem.

My code:

```
let quantity = 10;
var width : CGFloat = 0.0;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        width = self.scrView.frame.width;

        for i in 0..<quantity {

            let xPos = width * CGFloat(i);
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: width, height: self.scrView.frame.height))
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 50)
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.text = "\(i + 1)"

            label.backgroundColor = .randomColor()
            scrView.addSubview(label);
        }

        scrView.contentSize.width = width * CGFloat(quantity + 1);

    }
```

The pink color on the left side is from the previous "page".

[image]

And again, note the purple color on the left side from the previous (number 8) page.

[image]

The first page seems fine. However the higher the number the greater the offset. I want to cover the whole visible area for 1 label.

Does somebody knows an solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.

Note that the size of the scrollView can change after `viewDidLoad` as a result of *Auto Layout*.  A better place to set up your scrollView would be in an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  The size of the scrollView will be established by then.  But be careful, because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will run multiple times, so make sure you only set up your scrollView once.

---

This is not your bug, but your `contentSize.width` is too big.  You don't need to add `1` to `quantity` since there are exactly `quantity` labels in your scrollView content area.

```
scrView.contentSize.width = width * CGFloat(quantity)
```

Also, Swift doesn't need the `;` at the ends of lines, so delete those.